# Virtualbox: Windows 7 raw disk guest on Linux suddently boots stop 7b

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, virtualbox

I spend most of my time in Linux, but for as rarely as I use Windows I load my dual-boot partition in Virtualbox 4.3.20 via raw disk access. I've set this up on a few machines and I've been using this particular configuration for nearly two years without issues.

Sometime in the last month, the virtual machine stopped booting and halts at a blue screen with a STOP 7B error. I can load the Windows bootloader fine and see the first part of the boot animation. I can also boot Windows natively without issue.

I've had the raw disk mounted on a SATA bus for its entire life, and in native mode the drivers are set to Intel generic SATA drivers. Uninstalling the drivers and rebooting doesn't seem to help. What should I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work again after recreating the rawdisk vmdk. I must have upgraded from a prior version and broken something.